# python processes script not returning the same answer as direct bash command

Tags: python, bash, sockets, subprocess

hey first time question asker hope this is the correct format

i have a python scirpt which is trying to basically to use a bash command in this case telnet
this is the script

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout = proc.communicate('telnet 192.168.1.67 5555')
print (stdout)
```

i have a script on my other machine listening on port 5555
and the calling the script in bash returns

```
Connection closed by foreign host.
("Trying 192.168.1.67...\nConnected to 192.168.1.67.\nEscape character is '^]'.\n", None
```

and my other computer recognizes a connection but it closes the connection immediately 
while when i run the command

```
telnet 192.168.1.67 5555
```

it works fine and keeps the connection open

my question is how to i write a script which dose the same thing as the command "telnet 192.168.1.67 5555" and keeps the connection open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [socket — Low-level networking interfac](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html)

See the Python module of the week about [socket](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/).

Python 2 Example:

```
import socket, select, string, sys

if(len(sys.argv) < 3) :
    print 'Usage : python telnet.py hostname port'
    sys.exit()

host = sys.argv[1]
port = int(sys.argv[2])

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(2)

# connect to remote host
try :
    s.connect((host, port))
except :
    print 'Unable to connect'
    sys.exit()

print 'Connected to remote host'

while 1:
    socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]

    # Get the list sockets which are readable
    read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])

    for sock in read_sockets:
        #incoming message from remote server
        if sock == s:
            data = sock.recv(4096)
            if not data :
                print 'Connection closed'
                sys.exit()
            else :
                #print data
                sys.stdout.write(data)

        #user entered a message
        else :
            msg = sys.stdin.readline()
            s.send(msg)
```